# Where can I find the following S. Shelah's paper?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, paper-request

I've been trying to find the following article: "S. Shelah, *Remarks on cardinal invariants in topology*, General topology Appl. **7**(3) (1977), 251-259". I tried to go directly to the journal page, but it turns out that Issue 3 isn't registered there (see: [General Topology and its Applications](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/general-topology-and-its-applications/issues)).

Is there any other place where I can find this paper?

Comment: Have you tried the Shelah archive at https://shelah.logic.at/ ?

Comment: @AndreasBlass It's [entry 36 there](https://shelah.logic.at/papers/36/), but with no downloadable copy.

Comment: For what it's worth, the only paper in General Topology and Its Applications volume 7 issue 3 that I can find online is Paul Bankston's [*Ultraproducts in Topology*](http://www.mscs.mu.edu/~paulb/Paper/ult.pdf), 283–308. The contents of volume 7 issue 3 can be found online at https://doi.org/10.1016/0016-660X(79)90044-8.

Comment: I've asked our library to get a copy. I guess it won't happen sooner than in couple of weeks, though.

Comment: a summary may be found in https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0366.54004

Comment: Thank you so much, hopefully they have it! I have been told that one can find a review of the paper in Mathematical Reviews made by Eric K. van Douwen, but you need a subscription though.

Comment: please see my answer for a link to a scan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please get the pdf [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19tNBdYlUMe-KLWUHo04u8H3pC3Xb2hbF/view?usp=drivesdk).

note that the text itself starts on page 5.

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you so much.

Comment: it's a pleasure to help less fortunate, w.r.t. library access, colleagues.